# Generate consistent person data

Tags: python

I want to use [Faker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-factory) to generate some data for tests.

But I have trouble generating consitent data for a single user:

```
>>> from faker import Factory

>>> fake = Factory.create()

>>> fake.name()
>>> u'Tayshaun Corkery'

>>> fake.email()
>>> u'kaitlynn40@yahoo.com'
```

As you see the email doesn't reflect the previously generated name. The docs say:

> Each call to method `fake.name()` yields a different (random) result.
>   This is because faker forwards `faker.Generator.method_name()` calls
>   to `faker.Generator.format(method_name)`.

Is there a way to generate consistent person data without writing much of additional code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Factory_Boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for it. It comes with built-in Faker and allows you to create, from an already generated attribute (a name, a surname, for example) a "lazy" attribute (an email for example) using the previous data.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a script that will use the first name and last name from faker and add a random number between 1 and 1000, put them together to make a fake generated email with a number to make it look more legit (Example IanCartwright268@gmail.co.uk), here is the code

```
from faker import Faker # Import Faker And Random For The Random Number #
from random import *
fake = Faker('en_GB') # Sets Faker's Location To Great Britain#
fn = ((fake.first_name())) # Makes The First Name Into A Veriable #
ln = ((fake.last_name())) # Makes The Last Name Into A Veriable #
rn = str (randint(1,1000)) # Makes A Random Number From 1 To 1000 And It Used To Add A Random Number To The End Of The Email To Make It Look Legit #
email = (fn + ln + rn + "@gmail.co.uk") # Adds The First Name, Last Name And The Random Number And The Extension '@gmail.co.uk' #
print("First Name: " + fn + "\n" + "last Name: " + ln + "\n" + "Email: " + email) # Prints The Whole Output#
```

I Hope This Helps, If You Need Any More Help Message Me On Twitter @R00T_H4X0R

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid not. Let me say if there was one, which apparently supposed to be simple_profile() or seed(), but actually doesn't work out that way.

I guess the only inconsistent data as concerned is email. It doesn't even take time to fake one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NodeJS and [faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/faker),

```
    let firstName = faker.name.firstName()
    let lastName = faker.name.lastName()
    let email = faker.internet.email(firstName,lastName)
```

This will generate realistic name and email combinations like

```
firstName, lastName :  Flavie Waelchi
email :                Flavie_Waelchi@example.net
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in MERN, this is JS. I think you can get an idea of how I overcame this issue and, get the same output all the time. you can add "faker.seed(123;" this 123 can be changed according to your wish. Hope this helps you

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question.